# MySQL on duplicate key delete

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, duplicates

I am looking for a (not too convoluted) solution for a MySQL problem. Say I have the following table (with a joint index on group and item):

```
Group     item
nogroup   item_a
group_a   item_a
```

Then, eventually, item_a no longer belongs to group_a. So I want to do something like:

```
update table set group = "nogroup" where item = "item_a" on duplicate key delete.
(obviously this is not a valid symtax but I am looking for a way around this)
```

I still want to keep a copy of the record with nogroup because, if later on, item_a comes back, i can change its group back to group_a or any other group depending on the case. Whenever item_a is added, there is an insert and it copies all the data from the nogroup record and sets a proper group label. At that point there are two records for item_a: one with group_a and one with no group. The reason it is done this way is to reuse previous data as much as possible as a new entry(with no previous record) is much more involved and take significantly more time and processing.

Say an item belongs to group_a and group_b but suddenly it does not belong to any group: the first update to set group to "nogroup" will work but the second update will create a duplicate key entry error.

The option of "not updating the group column at all" and using "insert on duplicate key update" does not work because there won't be duplicates when the groups are different and this will lead to cases where an item does not belong to a group anymore and yet the record will still be present in the database. The option of verifying if "nogroup" exists first and then updating it to a specific group does not work either because if item_a belongs to more than one group this would update all other records to the same group.

Basically, an item can belong to 1) any number of groups including "nogroup" or 2) solely belonging to "nogroup" and there should always be a copy of at least nogroup somewhere in the database.

It looks like I won't be able to do this in just one query but if someone has a clean way of dealing with this, that would be much appreciated. Maybe some of my assumptions above are wrong and there is an easy way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your whole process of maintaining this items-to-groups mapping sounds too complicated. Why not just have a table that has a mapping? Then, when an item is removed from a group, delete it from the table. When it is added, add it to the table.  Don't bother with "nogroup".

If you want an archive table, then create one. Have an `insert`/`update`/`delete` trigger (whichever is or are appropriate) that will populate an archive with information that you want to keep over time.

I do not understand why re-using an existing row would be beneficial in terms of performance. There is no obvious *database* reason why this would be the case.

I am also confused as to why you need a "nogroup" tag at all. If you need a list of items, maintain that list in its own table. And call the table `Items` -- a much clearer name than "nogroup".

Comment: I had a solution for this; I just do it two passes(query) one to insert and one to do the cleaning. I was just wondering if someone would have a clever way to do it in one pass (would simplify the process and ensure there are no omissions). Inserting a new record is definitely not a problem - getting the information that goes into that record is the problem but I took care of that. Still, judging by the number of persons asking for "update on key duplicate delete" on google, maybe that should be considered as an option. Thanks for your time and your response.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Gordan's approach. However if you have to do it with a single table it cannot be done in 1 SQL query. You will have to use 2 queries 1 for update and 1 for delete.